# Android: Instrumentation tests running erratically on Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-espresso

My instrumentation tests run quite nicely on Nexus phones and tablets, passing consistently 100% of the time.  Running the same tests on Samsung devices is completely flaky.  The same test being run 3 times can pass on try #1, timeout on try #2, and throw an exception on try #3.

Is there something about Samsung Android phones & tablets that make them poor candidates for automated UI testing?  If Samsung devices have some quirks that have workarounds, does anyone have any suggested reading on the topic?

If it matters, I'm using Espresso as part of the test suite.

Comment: I had problems on Samsung devices using Espresso when click becomes long click. This was the main reason to not to use them in automated tests.

Comment: @denys thanks.  I bumped into a click event problem with Samsung devices before on an unrelated manner.  I'll look into the click event and see what's happening.

Comment: Did you make sure to disable animations?

Comment: @CarlAnderson Yes, animations are/were disabled.  [Here's the code](https://github.com/amorphid/android-click_on_the_floaty_bits/commit/b19e34c34e207a94ec27a2599d12c5b291b3f727) if you wanna check it out

Comment: If you solved the problem on your own, you should post the solution here so others can benefit. Strange that moving the onClick handlers from XML to Java solved the problem.